# Top view in a LinearLayout embedded in a ScrollView only half visible

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app, I insert pairs of spinners into a linearlayout, which is inside a scrollview. Problem is, when I add enough spinners, the top two are partially obscured.  Here's what I'm talking about.

[image: :(]

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/ChordHeader"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addChordButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Add Chord" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/spacetext1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="  "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/removeChordButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Remove Chord" />
 </LinearLayout>

 <ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ChordList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >
```

(Spinners get inserted here)

```
</LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And here is the code that inserts spinners into the list, if the problem is with that.

```
    Spinner chordName = new Spinner(this);
    Spinner chordType = new Spinner(this);

    LinearLayout container = new LinearLayout(this);
    container.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout chordList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ChordList);

    chordName.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 80, 50));
    chordName.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
    container.addView(chordName); //add name spinner to container

    chordType.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 80, 50));
    chordType.setAdapter(typeAdapter);
    container.addView(chordType); //add type spinner to container
    container.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.bottom_bar);
    container.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);


    chordList.addView(container); //add container to list layout
```

Comment: I don't understand the issue... you put in too many to fit.  Scroll so the ones you want are visible.  What else do you expect it to do???

Comment: thats because you are setting the height of the scrollview to "match_parent" instead of "wrap_content"... and just as comment.. is not a good idea to have an "empty" textView just to leave some space between 2 elements try using the Gravity attribute.

Comment: Barak, it doesn't scroll up any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my layout.. try it out :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ChordHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:drawable/bottom_bar">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addChordButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="Add Chord" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/removeChordButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:ellipsize="middle"
            android:text="Remove Chord" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ChordHeader"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ChordList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now for the buttons you might want to set a dimen if you really want them the same size.
Here is how to store dimensions in Android : [More Resource Types: Dimension](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a reference to the top item in the list and then request focus on it, after you are done adding the spinners.

```
chordList.getChildAt(0).requestFocus();
```